Flask applicaiton how to render templates with new variables
I'm building my flask app and when i got the user's input for their information, i want to load the page againa and show the infos
So far i tried to render the page again itself the parameters are too complex to set up
i also tried to render another template but it does not work
  if fin_json:
                name = fin_json.get("client_name")
                phone = fin_json.get("phone_number")
                details = fin_json.get("reservation_details")

                print("Client Name:", name)
                print("Phone Number:", phone)

                if details:
                    checkin_date = details.get("checkin_date")
                    checkout_date = details.get("checkout_date")
                    preferences = details.get("preferences")

                    print("Check-in Date:", checkin_date)
                    print("Checkout Date:", checkout_date)
                    print("Preferences:", preferences)

                    # Render the template again with updated variables
                    return redirect(url_for('booking', name=name, phone=phone, checkin_date=checkin_date, checkout_date=checkout_date, preferences=preferences))

                   

@app.route('/booking')
def booking():
    name = request.args.get('name')
    phone = request.args.get('phone')
    checkin_date = request.args.get('checkin_date')
    checkout_date = request.args.get('checkout_date')
    preferences = request.args.get('preferences')

    # Debugging prints
    print("Rendering booking page with details:")
    print(f"Name: {name}")
    print(f"Phone: {phone}")
    print(f"Check-in Date: {checkin_date}")
    print(f"Checkout Date: {checkout_date}")
    print(f"Preferences: {preferences}")

    return render_template(
        "booking.html",
        name=name,
        phone=phone,
        checkin_date=checkin_date,
        checkout_date=checkout_date,
        preferences=preferences
    )

